# Patching instance class requires base class to be in the same unit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am using following function to patch an instance class of an existing object.
The reason is that I need to patch a protected function of a third party class.

```
procedure PatchInstanceClass(Instance: TObject; NewClass: TClass);
type
  PClass = ^TClass;
begin
  if Assigned(Instance) and Assigned(NewClass)
    and NewClass.InheritsFrom(Instance.ClassType)
    and (NewClass.InstanceSize = Instance.InstanceSize) then
  begin
    PClass(Instance)^ := NewClass;
  end;
end;
```

But for some reason, the code only works if the the base class is defined in my own unit.
Why's that? Is there a work-around to make it work without it?

**This doesn't work**

```
 unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, wwdblook, Wwdbdlg;

type
  TwwDBLookupComboDlg = class(Wwdbdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg); // This is necessary
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    wwDBLookupComboDlg1: TwwDBLookupComboDlg;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TButtonEx = class(TButton)
  end;

  TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx = class(TwwDBLookupComboDlg)
  end;

procedure PatchInstanceClass(Instance: TObject; NewClass: TClass);
type
  PClass = ^TClass;
begin
  if Assigned(Instance) and Assigned(NewClass)
    and NewClass.InheritsFrom(Instance.ClassType)
    and (NewClass.InstanceSize = Instance.InstanceSize) then
  begin
    PClass(Instance)^ := NewClass;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PatchInstanceClass(Button1, TButtonEx);
  showmessage(Button1.ClassName); // Good: TButtonEx

  PatchInstanceClass(wwDBLookupComboDlg1, TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx);
  showmessage(wwDBLookupComboDlg1.ClassName); // Bad: TwwDBLookupComboDlg (should be TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx)
end;

end.
```

**This works** (The only difference is the re-definition of TwwDBLookupComboDlg)

```
type
  TwwDBLookupComboDlg = class(wwdbdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg); // <------ added!

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PatchInstanceClass(wwDBLookupComboDlg1, TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx);
  showmessage(wwDBLookupComboDlg1.ClassName); // shows TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx :-)
end;

end.
```

While working on that example, I found out that this phenomenon only happens with TwwDBLookupComboDlg , but not with TButton . I don't know why. Unfortunately, wwdbdlg.pas is not free.

---

**Update:**

I found out: If I compare `TButton` and `TButtonEx`, both values are 608.

If I compare `wwdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg` and `TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx`, then the sizes are 940 and 944.

If I compare `Unit1.TwwDBLookupComboDlg` and `TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx`, then the sizes are 944 and 944.

So... the actual problem is: If I define `TwwDBLookupComboDlg = class(Wwdbdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg);` , the instance size grows by 4 byte!

A simple demonstration. This program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Dialogs;

type
  TOpenDialog = class(Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog);
  TOpenDialogEx = class(TOpenDialog);

begin
  Writeln(Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.InstanceSize);
  Writeln(TOpenDialog.InstanceSize);
  Writeln(TOpenDialogEx.InstanceSize);
  Readln;
end.
```

emits

```
188
192
192
```

when compiled with Delphi 2007. However, with XE7 the output is:

```
220
220
220
```

While this issue occurs on `TOpenDialog`, it does not happen with `TCommonDialog`.

**Update 2: Minimal example**

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, Dialogs;

type
  TOpenDialog = class(TCommonDialog)
  private
    FOptionsEx: TOpenOptionsEx;
  end;

  TOpenDialogEx = class(Project1.TOpenDialog);

begin
  Writeln(Project1.TOpenDialog.InstanceSize); // 100
  Writeln(TOpenDialogEx.InstanceSize); // 104
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Couldn't we have a [mcve] that we can paste and execute directly? Otherwise we have to build it ourselves. Each and every one of us. Isn't that a terrible inefficiency? If you did it then we'd all benefit. Isn't the onus on your to make it as simple as possible for us to help you?

Comment: Ok, here it is:http://pastebin.com/SL2gKBTR . While working on that example, I found out that this phenomenon only happens with TwwDBLookupComboDlg , but not with TButton . I don't know why. Unfortunately, wwdbdlg.pas is not free.

Comment: Shouldn't be in an offsite link. Should be in the question. But if it only happens with a control that I don't have then I certainly cannot help. Also, it's still not complete. If you put it into a console app then it would be complete.

Comment: It should actually be `TwwDBLookupComboDlg = class(Wwdbdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg);` . The code was from a previous pastebin code version. I have found out something more... If I compare TButton and TButtonEx, both values are 608. If I compare wwdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg and TwwDBLookupComboDlgEx, then the sizes are 940 and 944. So... the actual problem is: If I do `TwwDBLookupComboDlg = class(Wwdbdlg.TwwDBLookupComboDlg);` , the instance size grows by 4 byte!

Comment: OK, that's good debugging. Do you have the source code for this class. Can you make a copy of that class, and whittle it down to something small the reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, You can try `TOpenDialog` same results. without the interposer class the new `TOpenDialogEx` has 4 extra bytes to the instace size.

Comment: @kobik Not for me. This program emits 220 each time: `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TOpenDialog = class(Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog);
  TOpenDialogEx = class(TOpenDialog);

begin
  Writeln(Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.InstanceSize);
  Writeln(TOpenDialog.InstanceSize);
  Writeln(TOpenDialogEx.InstanceSize);
  Readln;
end.
`

Comment: In Delphi 2007 I get 188, 192, 192

Comment: Interesting. I'm on XE7. I think you need to add the delphi version to the tags. Actually, that program in my previous post would make an excellent addition to the question since it really narrows down the issue. Let me do that.....

Comment: Same results in Delphi 7. `Dialogs.TOpenDialog.InstanceSize` is 4 bytes short.

Comment: TOpenDialog is 4 bytes short, while TCommonDialog and TComponent is equal. Hm...

Comment: If I could persuade the Emba servers to register my Delphi 6 then I'd be able to look at it there. But they won't play ball. Oh well.

Comment: Afaik Delphi 6 could be run without registration. Only for Delphi 7 it was mandatory. If you have Windows 10, then there is an issue with Delphi 6; in that case I wrote a small workaround here : http://www.viathinksoft.de/?page=codelib&showid=121 (sorry, it's German, but you can try Google Translate)

Comment: I have found the reason (but not the problem)! This is the minimum definition of TOpenDialog:  `  TOpenDialog = class(TCommonDialog) private FOptionsEx: TOpenOptionsEx; end; `  . So if this private symbol is removed, the sizes are equal again.

Comment: I have updated my question with update #2.     (Why don't the backticks work in my comment above?)

Comment: BTW, why do you use `PatchInstanceClass` in the first place instead of an interposer class to handle all `TwwDBLookupComboDlg` instances?

Comment: I think there's more to it than that. I've got a much simpler repro.

Answer (score 10):

This appears to be an oddity (perhaps a bug) in the compiler behaviour for older versions of the compiler. I've whittled this down to the following code:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TClass1 = class
    FValue1: Double;
    FValue2: Integer;
  end;

  TClass2 = class(TClass1);

begin
  Writeln(TClass1.InstanceSize);
  Writeln(TClass2.InstanceSize);

  Writeln;
  Writeln(Integer(@TClass1(nil).FValue1));
  Writeln(Integer(@TClass1(nil).FValue2));

  Writeln;
  Writeln(Integer(@TClass2(nil).FValue1));
  Writeln(Integer(@TClass2(nil).FValue2));

  Readln;
end.
```

On Delphi 6 the output is:

```
20
24

8
16

8
16
```

The compiler appears to handle alignment differently for the two class declarations. The class contains a double which has 8 byte alignment, followed by a 4 byte integer. So the class really should have 4 bytes of padding at the end to make its size be a multiple of 8. The first class does not have this padding, the second one does.

The code here proves that the offsets to the fields have not changed, and the difference is just in the padding at the end of the type that exists to achieve alignment.

Obviously you aren't going to get a patch for the Delphi 2007 compiler. My suspicion is that you can remove the check that `NewClass.InstanceSize = Instance.InstanceSize` and your patching code will still behave correctly. Then the onus is on you to ensure that you don't add any data members to your patching class.

Another approach might be to use a different mechanism to patch the code. Without more knowledge of the original problem it's hard for me to say what that might be.

Comment: Is it safe to use `{$ALIGN 4}` is such case?

Comment: @kobik Does that have the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, size is the same in both cases. but its 16 for both classes (instead of 20,24).

Comment: @kobik the real test is to check what happens when you apply the directive only to the derived class. Because in the real world case that's the only one you control.

Comment: And it seems that doesn't help